# How can I get efficiently QuerySet of a Model from another QuerySet without using values or values_list

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I have **Visit** model and **Patient** model

```
class Visit(models.Model):
    patient = model.ForeignKey(Patient)
    # other fields

class Patient(models.Model):
    # other fields
```

I have QuerySet of **Visit** like this

```
visits = Visit.objects.filter(#conditions)
```

How can I get efficiently QuerySet of Patient's instances from the visits QuerySet without using values or values_list. i.e.

```
patients_ids = visits.values_list("Patient__id", flat=True).distinct()
patients = Patient.objects.filter(id__in=patients_ids)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit difficult to understand what you're asking but I think this might be what you want:

```
visits = Visit.objects.filter(name=somename, count=something)
```

To get the patients corresponding to that you would do:

```
patients = Patient.objects.filter(visit__name=somename, visit__count=something).distinct()
```

Explanation:

The `Patient` model gets a backwards many-to-one reference called the lower case of the other model by default (`visit` in this case). You can then query through that relation using the double underscore feature `__` and do the same tests you were going to do in your `Visit` filter.

[Source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/)